# Linux terminal emulator for tmux control mode

Tags: linux, tmux, terminal-emulator

Is there a terminal emulator for Linux that supports tmux control mode?

I'm searching for an equivalent to iterm2. iterm2 does the job under Mac OSX.

Comment: This link may help for you http://askubuntu.com/questions/7605/what-terminal-emulators-are-available-for-heavy-terminal-users

Comment: Here is a feature request for Terminator: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1301605

Comment: There is a question on unix SE:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189805/108702

Answer (score 0):

Not right now. You have to keep in mind that tmux control mode was added to tmux by the developer of iTerm2 to be used specifically with iTerm2.

I agree that the control mode feature is fantastic, especially when combined with SSH, but it's gonna take some time before other terminal emulators release integrations with it.

It's my one regret of deciding to switch away from Mac.

Terminator does have an open feature request tmux control mode integration, but work on it is stalled: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1301605